# querydsl using parent query entitypath in subquery

Tags: subquery, querydsl

I am trying to represent the following query in querydsl:

```js
select a1.agreement_id, ad1.agreement_detail_id
from agreement a1
  inner join agreement_details ad1 on a1.agreement_id=ad1.agreement_id 
where ad1.transaction_id in (
  select max(ad2.transaction_id) 
  from agreement_details ad2 
    inner join agreement a2 on ad2.agreement_id=a2.agreement_id 
  where 
    ad2.transaction_id<=1234
    and a2.agreement_id=a1.agreement_id 
    and a2.entity_split_id=5678 
) 
order by a1.agreement_id asc
```

However, I'm having trouble getting querydsl to use a table from the parent query in the where clause of the subquery.  For example, if I write code like the following:

```java
QAgreement a1 = QAgreement.agreement;
QAgreementDetails ad1 = QAgreementDetails.agreementDetails;
QAgreement a2 = QAgreement.agreement;
QAgreementDetails ad2 = QAgreementDetails.agreementDetails;
HibernateQuery query = getHibernateQuery();
query.from(a1)
    .innerJoin(a1.agreementDetailsesByAgreementId, ad1)
    .fetch()
    .where(ad1.transactionId.in(
      new JPASubQuery().from(ad2)
        .innerJoin(ad2.agreementByAgreementId, a2)
        .where(ad2.transactionId.loe(maxTransactionId))
        .where(a1.agreementId.eq(a2.agreementId))
        .where(a2.entitySplitByEntitySplitId.entitySplitId.eq(entitySplitId))
        .list(ad2.transactionId.max())))
        .orderBy(a1.agreementId.asc());
```

and execute it, the resulting SQL looks like

```sql
select  -- Some columns removed for brevity
   agreement0_.agreement_id as agreemen1_0_0_,
   agreementd1_.agreement_detail_id as agreemen1_11_1_ 
from
   agreement agreement0_ 
inner join
   agreement_details agreementd1_ 
       on agreement0_.agreement_id=agreementd1_.agreement_id 
where
   agreementd1_.transaction_id in (
       select
           max(agreementd2_.transaction_id) 
       from
           agreement_details agreementd2_ 
       inner join
           agreement agreement3_ 
               on agreementd2_.agreement_id=agreement3_.agreement_id 
       where
           agreementd2_.transaction_id<=1234
           and agreement3_.agreement_id=agreement3_.agreement_id 
           and agreement3_.entity_split_id=5678 
   ) 
order by
   agreement0_.agreement_id asc
```

You can see that the alias of the Agreement EntityPath a1 is not being used in the subquery and is being replaced by the alias of the Agreement EntityPath a2.  Is there something else I have to do in querydsl to be able to produce this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you don't use unique variables

```
QAgreement a1 = QAgreement.agreement;
QAgreementDetails ad1 = QAgreementDetails.agreementDetails;
QAgreement a2 = QAgreement.agreement;
QAgreementDetails ad2 = QAgreementDetails.agreementDetails;
```

In this case a1 and a2 as well as ad1 and ad2 refer to the same path.

The variable names in the Java code don't matter, you need to use them for example like this

```
QAgreement a1 = new QAgreement("a1");
QAgreementDetails ad1 = new QAgreementDetails("ad1");
QAgreement a2 = new QAgreement("a2");
QAgreementDetails ad2 = new QAgreementDetails("ad2");
```